# Two versions of my input function, recursion vs while-loop?

Tags: python, recursion, input, while-loop

I need to have a function which returns a guaranteed input of type `float`.
To implement this I came up with a recursive way, but only seconds later I realized I could use a `while`-loop just as well.

So, which one is preferred?
Is there a reason to use one over the other?

I'm pretty sure I should go with the `while` loop due to Python's lack of tail calls (afaik?), but I'm still not 100% confident.

Here are both my functions:

```
def inputf(prompt=None):
    try:
        return float(input(prompt))
    except ValueError:
        return inputf(prompt)

def inputf2(prompt=None):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Comment: What reason do you have to be you worried about tail call optimization?  For your use case [i]there is almost certainly no reason to optimize this[/i].  Much better to focus on optimizing the part of the code that is algorithmically complex and keep this bit of code simpler (which as others have said, is best accomplished with `while`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that both are acceptable, and there is no huge advantage over either of them. It is unlikely (but you never know) that a user fail to input a number over a hundred times with the recursive function.

If you want to stick with recursion, but worried about reaching the [recursion limit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit) you can set it to a higher value, but that would be for an extreme case scenario.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

Although, I would probably go with the while loop as it is probably easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

I guess with the recursive function, you'll end up with this exception:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

But that's after 256 recursions (or even much more, depends on the system you're running Python on).

Comment: What do you mean by "stop taking input somewhere"? It already stops as soon as the user inputs a float number.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the preferred method would be to use the `while` loop.  If your intent is to have an infinite loop, it will be much easier for someone else to read it that way if you use `while True:` instead of using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems when i tried to make a code for normalised variable in 1000 or so steps (look my qiestions)....When I used recursive function i kept getting "recursion depth" error and many experienced programers told that i should use while loop because it uses less memory...